# SplitView navigation issue in ipad

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller

i implemented a split view in my app. When my app launch it shows fine.

**masterview=Leftside view & detailView = Home view**

But my master view also contains 2 Table view. when i clicked the any row of table view, the **detail view(Now, class view) is not get display**.

Mean i want to disply display mutiple detail view as per master view's table row selected.

my code for split view is as follow:

```
// AppDelegate.h

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

LeftViewController *masterViewController = [[LeftViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LeftViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] ;
        UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController] ;

        HomeViewController *detailViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];


        masterViewController.home_Detail = detailViewController;

        self.splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init] ;
        self.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;




        self.splitViewController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterNavigationController,detailNavigationController, nil];

        self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;

        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}



//LeftView.m

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    [self.appDelegate.splitViewController viewWillDisappear:YES];
    NSMutableArray *viewControllerArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[self.appDelegate.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] viewControllers]];

    [viewControllerArray removeAllObjects];

    if (tableView==tbl_class) 
    {

       self.class_VC=[[Class_Vice_ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Class_Vice_ViewController" bundle:nil];


        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:[[[classNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"class_id"]intValue] forKey:@"psel_class"];

        NSLog(@"%d",[[[classNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"class_id"]intValue]);



        [viewControllerArray addObject:self.class_VC];
        self.appDelegate.splitViewController.delegate = self.class_VC;

        [[self.appDelegate.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] setViewControllers:viewControllerArray animated:NO];
        [class_VC viewWillAppear:YES];

    }
}
```

**Help me to Solve this issue**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offending line is this one in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method:

```
[self.appDelegate.splitViewController viewWillDisappear:YES];
```

I don't know why you put that in, but if you remove it, it should work. You also don't need this line:

```
[self.class_VC viewWillAppear:YES];
```

While it is quite common to override viewWillAppear: and viewWillDisappear:, you almost never call them like you're doing.